# Jquery. Как выбрать дату из unix timestamp?

Tags: jquery, дата, timestamp

Есть дата в формате unix timestamp, подскажите пожалуйста каким образом (и возможно ли) выбрать информацию в таком формате - (отдельно дата, отдельно время без секунд)?
23.05.2016
09:45

Answer (score 0):

для этого есть специальная библиотека, честно говоря не помню как называется, специально для работы с датами на фронте. Кажется moment называется.

поставь ее и потом можно будет вот так делать:

moment.unix(timestamp).format('DD.MM.YY HH:mm')